# HTACCESS Rewrite not working as expected

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have below directory structure on my web-server

```
     --public_html
       --TEST 
         --LATEST
           --- V1
               ----index.php
           --- V2
               ----index.php
           --- V3
               ----index.php
```

Whenever a request is sent to example.com/TEST/LATEST , I want to redirect to one of the version which I will specify in a .HTACCESS file.

I tried below two combinations with .htaccess file in TEST/LATEST folder

**Option 1**

```
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^TEST/LATEST/$ http://www.yourdomain.com/TEST/LATEST/V1/ [R=301,L]
```

---

**Options 2**

```
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^TEST/LATEST/(.*)$ /TEST/LATEST/V1/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But both are not working. Can anyone help please, I am new to .HTACCESS concepts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `.htaccess` code in the `public_html` folder.
Or change, and use in the `LATEST` folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ V1/ [R=301,L]
```